# Stack at laravel query with relation

Tags: php, laravel

I need your help.
I have this query but I am getting trouble

I have these two tables:

```
users
---------------------
 id | name | surname
---------------------

users_ratings 
-------------------------------------
 id | user_id | customer_id | rating
-------------------------------------
```

Not every user has a rating.

I am trying to show on a view in Laravel every user and it's rating.

```
$users=User::where('role','=','4')->paginate(8);
$data = array();
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $ratings = UserRating::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
    $nr = UserRating::where('user_id',  $user->id)->count();
    $sum = 0;


        foreach ($ratings as $rate) {
            if ($rate->rating != "") {
                $rating = $rate->rating;
                $sum = $sum + $rating;

            }
        }

        if ($nr == 0) {
            $avg = 0;
        } else {
            $avg = ($sum / $nr);
        }

    }
    else {

        $avg=0;
    }
        $object = [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'rating' => number_format($avg, 3, '.', ','),
            'user'=>$user
        ];

        array_push($data, $object);

       return view('pages.users', ['data' => $data]);
```

Now I am showing in view:

```
@foreach($data as $d)
    {{$d->id}}
    {{$d->rating}]
    {{$d->user->name}}
@endforeach
```

I know that something is wrong here. It shows

> "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object....

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
@foreach($data as $d)
{{$d['id']}}
{{$d['rating']}}

@endforeach
```

**OR**

```
@foreach($data as $key => $d)
    {{$d[$key]->id}}
    {{$d[$key]->rating}]
    {{$d[$key]->user->name}}
@endforeach
```

**Updated Answer**

```
@foreach($data as $key => $d)
  @foreach($d as $rsltDetails)
    {{$rsltDetails['id']}}
    {{$rsltDetails['rating']}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: @Alphal1111: Please display result of `$object` before array_push (i.e `print('<pre style="color:red;">');
  print_r($object);
  print('</pre>');
  exit;`)

Comment: It shows: Array
(
    [id] => 27
    [rating] => 4.667
)    What i see is that it gets only one id, the problem might be at foreach loop

Comment: @Alphal1111: Now please display result of `$data` before `return view('pages.users', ['data' => $data]);` (i.e print('<pre style="color:red;">'); print_r($data); print('</pre>'); exit;)

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [rating] => 4.667
        )

)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186463/discussion-between-alphal1111-and-saurabh-dhariwal).

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong here.

First, you have an n+1 query. You are fetching the users and inside the loop for each user, you are performing 2 additional queries.

```
$users = User::where('role','=','4')->paginate(8);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $ratings = UserRating::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
    $nr = UserRating::where('user_id',  $user->id)->count();
    $sum = 0;
    ...
}
```

**Solution:**

This code will execute only two queries.

```
// I am assuming the relation name between User and UserRating is ratings
$users = User::with('ratings')->where('role','=','4')->paginate(8);

return view('pages.users', compact('users));
```

In your view, you can easily print the values

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->id }}
    {{ number_format($user->ratings->avg('rating'), 3, '.', ',') }}
    {{ user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it that way is not a scalable solution and you will face the [N+1](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/) problem. 
I would suggest the following.

First, in your `App\User` model, define your relationship with `App\UserRating`:

```
use App\UserRating; 

public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserRating::class); 
}
```

Then, define your inverse relationship in `App\UserRating`

```
use App\User; 

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Finally, you could simplify your loop like this:

```
$users = User::where('role','=','4')
    ->with('ratings') // eager-load ratings
    ->paginate(8);

$results = []; 

foreach($users as $user) {
    // To access ratings you would do 
    // foreach($user->ratings as $rating) { }

    // To get the count you would do 
    // $user->ratings->count(); 
}
```

In your blade file, you could just do this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->id }}
    {{ number_format($user->ratings->avg('rating'), 3, '.', ',') }}
@endforeach
```

Doing it this way will solve your N+1 problem and leverages Laravel's Collections to make everything a little bit cleaner as well :)

Comment: Could you `dd($data)`  and show us the contents of the array?

Comment: I updated my answer, I understand it could have been a little bit confusing to see how you would use it in your blade :)